# Bootstrap column content display align to top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am trying to adjust date and time to be on the same level as city name. Please, see the picture below. Blue path line doesn't start from the beginning of city name because `.flight-date` element moved to next line. How can I make `date-time` element to grow to top instead of bottom or propose any other solutions how can I achieve the similar result?

[image]

[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyyzdP?editors=110)

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="roundtrip">
  <div class="trip col-xs-5">Outbound
    <div class="flight">

              <div class="date-time col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-1">
                <div class="flight-time pull-right">12:40</div>
                <div class="flight-date pull-right">Friday 11 Sep</div>
              </div>  
              <div class="col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-2">
                Los Angeles
              </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flight-path"></div>
    <div class="flight">Chicago</div>
    <div class="connection">5hr wait</div>
    <div class="flight">Chicago</div>
    <div class="flight-path"></div>
    <div class="flight">New York</div>
    <div class="connection">2hr wait</div>
    <div class="flight">New York</div>
    <div class="flight-path"></div>
    <div class="flight">Amsterdam</div>
  </div>
  <!-- just padding: --><div class="col-xs-2"></div>
  <div class="trip col-xs-5">Inbound
    <div class="flight">Amsterdam</div>
    <div class="flight-path"></div>
    <div class="flight">Los Angeles</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

LESS:

```
body {padding: 2em 0 0 2em}

.roundtrip {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.trip {
  //width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  //margin: 0px 3px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flight {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.date-time{
  vertical-align:top
}


.flight-path {
  width: 6px;
  min-height: 85px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #6090FF;
}

.connection {
  height: 40px;
  align-self: center;

  width: 70px;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox like this:

```css
body {
    padding: 2em 0 0 2em
}
.align-bottom {  /*added*/
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.roundtrip {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: stretch;
}
.trip {
    //width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    //margin: 0px 3px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.flight {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.date-time {
    text-align: center;
}
.flight-path {
    width: 6px;
    min-height: 85px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    align-self: center;
    background-color: #6090FF;
}
.connection {
    height: 40px;
    align-self: center;
    width: 70px;
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="roundtrip">
        <div class="trip col-xs-12">Outbound
            <div class="flight align-bottom"> <!--added the class 'align-bottom'-->
                <div class="date-time col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-3">
                    <div class="flight-time">12:40</div>
                    <div class="flight-date">Friday 11 Sep</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-2">Los Angeles</div>
            </div>
            <div class="flight-path"></div>
            <div class="flight">Chicago</div>
            <div class="connection">5hr wait</div>
            <div class="flight">Chicago</div>
            <div class="flight-path"></div>
            <div class="flight">New York</div>
            <div class="connection">2hr wait</div>
            <div class="flight">New York</div>
            <div class="flight-path"></div>
            <div class="flight">Amsterdam</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check this out for more info about [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick extra qustion, how do I make `12:30` aligned on the middle of date element `Friday 11 Sep`? Thanks again!

Comment: I,m glad to help you, the thing is you have `class="date-time col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-1"` on the container so the width of it is to small so do this: change it by `date-time col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-3`, set it `text-align: center` and remove the class `pull-right` form `flight-time` and `flight-date`